# reproduce Got an error reading communication packets in Mysql

Tags: mysql

How to reproduce the MySQL error "Got an error reading communication packets in MySQL" in MySQL error log. and what will happen to that connection. So that the MySQL will produce 2013 error..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Change the bind-address="Some IP"  restart MySQL server and try to start from localhost, you will get this error.

This error also occurs if port forwarding is disabled in SSH configuration (the configuration parameter 'AllowTcpForwarding' is set to 'no' in the 'sshd_config' file)

Comment: Not like this way ashwin. the DB we are using is in production network. still iam getting this error. and my DB error log filled with  this error.Can u provide any other possibility.Thanks